# XML Sitemap Not found error Wordpress

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am using "WordPress SEO by Yoast" plugin in my website http://www.goopro.org/ for seo and sitemap. But it shown me 404 error.

Here is sitemap url...
http://www.goopro.org/sitemap_index.xml

Please suggest why this error occurred. And How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Under the plugin settings for Yoast, have you checked the box to allow XML sitemap ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the file sitemap.xml is in the root directory of your website as it doesn't seem to be in there according to the 404 error you are receiving.